# Win32 Handling Internal Paint Messages

Tags: c++, winapi, message, directx-9

I am running a Win32 application in debug mode using Visual Studio. After switching to Visual Studio to debug my application does not continue its message loop...no messages are being sent...How do I handle focus/activation messages in order to resume the message loop?

EDIT:
This application uses DirectX9. I have 2 viewports( device swapchains ) to which I render geometry. If, during runtime, I click on a different window and then later try to return to my application both viewports are black( not being rendered to ). I set breakpoints in the message loop and am finding that one message( WM_PAINT ) is constantly being translated and dispatched, thus preventing my application from rendering. Below is message loop. 'bGotMsg' is always true after returning focus to my application...

EDIT: The problem seems to be an internal WM_PAINT message that is not being handled...I've checked the message that is continually being dispatched and the window handle is not one of my application...could it be some internal handle? MSDN indicates  here  that a WM_PAINT message will be sent while no other messages are in the queue or until the internal paint message is handled...How do I handle this message?

```
HRESULT WINAPI GDEMainLoop( HACCEL hAccel )
{
    HRESULT hr =S_OK;
    HWND hWnd = DXUTGetHWND();

    // Now we're ready to receive and process Windows messages.
    bool bGotMsg;
    MSG msg;
    msg.message = WM_NULL;
    PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_NOREMOVE );

    while( WM_QUIT != msg.message )
    {
        // Use PeekMessage() so we can use idle time to render the scene. 
        bGotMsg = ( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE ) != 0 );

        if( bGotMsg )
        {
            // Translate and dispatch the message
            if( /*!TranslateAccelerator( hWnd, hAccel, &msg )*/
                !IsDialogMessage( wnd.GetWindow( CWindowManager::EXPLORERBAR ), &msg )
                && !IsDialogMessage( wnd.GetSceneOutliner()->GetHWND(), &msg )
                && !IsDialogMessage( wnd.GetResourceOutliner()->GetHWND(), &msg )
                && !IsDialogMessage( wnd.GetProjectOutliner()->GetHWND(), &msg )
                && !IsDialogMessage( wnd.GetProjectDialog()->GetHWND(), &msg )
                && !IsDialogMessage( wnd.GetSceneDialog()->GetHWND(), &msg ) )
            {
                TranslateMessage( &msg );
                DispatchMessage( &msg );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if( FAILED( hr = GDERender3DEnvironment() ) )
            {
                DebugStringDX( MainClassName, "Failed to GDERender3DEnvironment() at GDEMainLoop()", __LINE__, hr );
                Alert( NULL, 
                    L"A failure occured while trying to render the 3D environment!",
                    L"Render Failure" );    

                PostQuitMessage( 0 );
            }
        }
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Typically, I set breakpoints on the first line of handlers I'd like to catch. When done, I just hit the 'play' button until one of the breakpoints is hit. The problem is that while the debugger is focussed, the app doesn't generate/process any more messages (wm_timer is one exception). So, the idea is to make the debugger stop if it gets to any code of interest.

Comment: right...i may have to open a new thread in gamedev...the app in question uses directx...somehow when the app loses focus the graphics device is not lost. Nor is it reset when i give focus to the main app window by 'clicking' and i end up with blank viewports...Nor does the application window continue handling messages...

Comment: Oooh. Sounds like a nasty situation. I may not have ventured a comment if I'd realized it was DirectX related. Sorry! I've definitely noticed unpleasant Alt-Tab behaviour with full-screen DirectX(3d) in the past. I guess it does something funky with the message loop. Not quite sure how I'd go about tackling the problem, to be honest. :)

Comment: This is the scenario where two monitors are extremely useful.

Comment: @selbie A dual-monitor setup won't help. The debuggee still loses focus when switching to the debugger. To prevent focus loss you need to use [Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx), either with two physical devices or a virtual machine.

Comment: remote debugging would work but my concern is for users who may switch to a different window while running my app...I need to force the application to resume...I just got the idea to try running the application in release mode to see if it behaves in the same manner so I'll try that...

Comment: @IInspectable actually the application seems to keep sending the same message over and over...the loop gets stuck...it just keeps sending WM_DEVICECHANGE ... i'm going to update my question above...i'm using multiple device swapchains( 2 in this case ) ...

Comment: The problem seems to be an internal WM_PAINT message that is not being handled...I've checked the message that is continually being dispatched and the window handle is not one of my application...could it be some internal handle? MSDN indicates [ here ]( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ) that a WM_PAINT message will be sent while no other messages are in the queue or until the internal paint message is handled...what do I do to handle this message?

Comment: You handle WM_PAINT by calling [`BeginPaint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183362(v=vs.85).aspx), painting whatever you need to inside the window, then calling `EndPaint`. It's the `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint` pair that tells Windows the WM_PAINT is no longer necessary.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks...by handling that message within the loop I was able to continue rendering( the message loop reached the 2nd condition ). There must still be a problem with my handling of paint messages somewhere in the application...shouldn't the DefWindowProc() function handle this? Perhaps the window in question belongs to a dialog and I need to use IsDialogMessage() to route the message properly...

Comment: @MarkRansom Do you know of any reason why the window handle that is to receive the WM_PAINT message would be invalid? I am calling GetWindowInfo() using the handle defined by the message struct...GetWindowInfo() fails and the error code is INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE( 1400 )...any idea?

Comment: Nope, sorry, don't know.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks i found it...